# iOs chrome does not reload the page on resize.

Tags: ios, google-chrome, reload, onresize

I am trying to reload the page when a user resizes the screen using the script bellow:

```
  $(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});
```

The real purpose of the above script is when a user rotates his/her iPad the page should reload. It works fine with Safari, but with chrome it doesn't reload at all. However, when I test it with PC Chrome  Emulator choosing iPad it works fine. The page gets reloaded on resize. Can you please write how can I fix the issue?